# Divide two rasters with different cell sizes using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, resolution, resampling

I've got two rasters of the exact same location (So every pixel in one raster is equivalent to the pixel in the other raster).

Raster A has a resolution of 6m per pixel.
Raster B has a resolution of 12m per pixel.

I want to divide Raster A by Raster B, and receive an output of 6m per pixel (Like raster A). I'm trying to do this via ArcMap and couldn't find a way to do it. Every method gives me an output resolution of 12m.

Any ideas or any other recommended method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resample your 12m raster to 6m in order for the division to work.
The basic way is to use [Resample](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresources.arcgis.com%2Fen%2Fhelp%2Fmain%2F10.1%2F0017%2F00170000009t000000.htm&ei=hYuSVKaNPILjau2EgvgD&usg=AFQjCNFpphAH_Ux1uZSAc0jqjTXjLQi--Q&sig2=xNAofGsQISHLJlihN6ZV3w) tool in the Data Management library.

Answer (score 2):

you can also modify the environment settings (bottom of your tool) of your tool and set a pixel size (raster analysis tab) of 6 m or select "minimum of input"(the default is maximum of input). This way you don't have to create a new raster. Of course, the advantage of resampling by yourself is that you have full control on the resampling method (within environment settings it will be nearest neighbour).